# Why use Compare and Swap over Thread Locking (Java/C++), is this governed by a certain frequency of contentions?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, locking, compare-and-swap

I understand the difference between Compare and Swap, and Thread locking for handling shared resources.
What I don't understand is why you would use Compare and Swap over Thread Locking.

When contention for resources is high Compare and Swap would result in a large amount of CPU cycle wastage, hence is better to use Thread Locking in this case.

When contention is low Compare and Swap ***could*** be used as CPU cycle wastage will be much lower, and the cost of this wastage ***might*** be lower than the cost of pausing and re-starting threads.

When contention is low the frequency of the Compare and Swap or Thread locking operation, which ever is used, will also be low, so the cost saving will be less significant.

I guess what i'm asking now is two questions.

What is the time cost of a few wasted cpu cycles VS the time cost of pausing and re-starting threads a few times, in Java / C++?

And is there a specific frequency of contentions (ie a number of contentions per second) that determines it is better to use one over the other?

I imagine this becomes much more important for low-latency applications.

Comment: It's not simple because of other factors.

Comment: "_When contention is low the frequency of the Compare and Swap or Thread locking operation, which ever is used, will also be low_" That's nonsense. A single thread can access the shared resource frequently, while another thread only accesses it infrequently.

Comment: What I meant was that if contention is low, the frequency of the operations used to handle the contention will be low, hence the cost saving when deciding which mechanism to use, becomes less significant.

Comment: @DDrmmr, Aranhakki is talking about a spin lock, not just a single CAS instruction.  If one thread frequently tries to get past a spin lock and other threads only rarely try, then the cost is insignificant, but if two or more threads frequently try (i.e., if there is contention), then the threads can burn up a lot of CPU time while waiting for the lock.  It gets *really* bad if the number of waiting threads exceeds the number of CPUs because the thread that holds the lock can be swapped out to let other threads "run" even though "run" just means spinning on the lock.

Comment: @aranhakki "_if contention is low, the frequency of the operations used to handle the contention will be low_" As I said, that doesn't make sense. If you have a shared resource you need to synchronize *every* access to that resource (in general). That can happen very frequently on one thread and only infrequently on another thread, meaning high frequency of using the synchronization mechanism while low frequency of contention for the shared resource.

Comment: @DDrmmr I see what you mean now, I think this gives us the answer, so a valid case for CAS operations is for the case you have stated above, this will reduce the time cost compared to using locks, are there any other cases you know off?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong.  You are arguing about CAS vs. Locking for "handling shared resources."  But CAS is not a substitute for locking in the same sense that a brick is not a substitute for a house:  CAS is an extremely primitive operation that can be used to _implement_ locking, and also to implement other useful things like wait-free queues & such.  If you are talking about spin-locks vs. Java's `synchronized` keyword, then you should take my previous comment seriously.  If you are talking about some wait-free algorithm vs. a locked implementation, then that's a whole 'nother ball of wax.

Comment: @james large, how are spin-locks different to wait-free algorithms? in  my eyes a spin-lock is a CAS operation in a loop, which is wait-free as it does not force the thread to pause...

Comment: or is a spin lock when your continuously trying to obtain a lock? but that wouldn't make sense as if you try to obtain a lock on a resource that is already locked you would be forced to pause and hence stop looping...

Comment: Different because the length of time that the other thread may have to wait for a spin-lock is unbounded.  In a correct, wait-free list algorithm, if thread A looses its time-slice immediately after a successful CAS operation, other threads may have to re-try, but they won't have to _wait_.  In the spin-lock case, if thread A looses its time-slice after a successful CAS, then other threads will spin on the lock until thread A becomes runnable again, finishes whatever amount of work it had to do, and finally unlocks the lock.

Comment: take a look at software based contention management algorithms for CAS like this: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~hendlerd/papers/EfficientCAS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what is the resource you have to share...remember that thread locking it self has to keep a variable that it compare and swaps internally, so the cost is already incurred..plus other cost involves thread context switch in and then out.